# Getting error with variable replacement in bash

Tags: bash, variables, replace

Good day people,

I am wondering why I am getting this error:

```
$ DEPARTAMENTO="San Andrés" ; mv `grep "${DEPARTAMENTO:0:5}" ARCHIVOS2MOVER |  sed 's/ /\\ /g'` "$DEPARTAMENTO" ; echo "$DEPARTAMENTO"
mv: cannot stat `./P1/San': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat `A_P1': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat `./P2/San': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat `A_P2': No such file or directory
San Andrés
```

This is a part of the file "ARCHIVOS2MOVER"

```
./Norte de Santander/Norte_P2
./P1/San A_P1
./P1/Total_P1
./P2/San A_P2
./P2/Total_P2
./Putumayo/Putum_P1
```

Thanks so much in advance for dropping me a clue

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to rename files with "San A" to have "San Andrés" instead?

Comment: Nope, the aim is to move files with the name _San A_P1_ and _San A_P1_ to the folder with the name _San Andrés_. The names of both files are obtained from the list file with the name _ARCHIVOS2MOVER_.

Comment: @BroSlow Doesn't help when he gets more than one line of output from grep like in this case.

Comment: @EtanReisner Woops, didn't notice that. +1 to your solution or just using a loop. I would imaging `evil` would also work, but that seems less appropriate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't escape spaces like that and have the shell operate on the escaped filenames the way you are trying to. But you don't need to do that either. This is what tools like `xargs` and such are for.

Try something like:

```
grep "${DEPARTAMENTO:0:5}" ARCHIVOS2MOVER | xargs -d '\n' mv -t "$DEPARTAMENTO"
```

Not that I think this is the best way to do this either but it will work given the data as given.

It might be better to loop over the lines of the file with `read` and and do the match line-by-line and `mv` each one if they match. Though I imagine many other options are also available depending on what the data sources are exactly.

Comment: @glennjackman Looks like not. I didn't trust that xargs was going to do things correctly with more than one argument though I clearly should have since if one argument works more than one has to. Updating.

Answer (score -2):

The `mv` is expanding to something like:

```
mv ./P1/San A_P1 "San Andrés"
```

So it is splitting the words on the space, then trying to move "./P1/San" and "A_P1" into "San Andrés".

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @glennjackman This answers the question, as I read it. Even if it's not overly helpful.